# How can I refactor the code in order to remove the break statement in a C# application

Tags: c#, sonarqube, break

I have a C# Windows application from where I'm making calls to a API using below code:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "Some URL"))
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");                                
            response = await myHttpHelper.SendHttpRequest(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);                             
        }
        break; // where the code smells is shown
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException )
    {
        if (++attemptCount > 3)
        {
            throw;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Usually what happens is the get request to APIs gets cancelled when ever there is some network issue. So what I have done is whenever the task is getting cancelled, I attempt it for three times. If it doesn't work , then I throw an exception to the calling method. If it is successful with in this 3 attempts, I'm breaking the loop.

Now when I run Sonar analysis on my code, it is showing to remove break statement and refactor the code. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe try using the attemptCount  for your while loop?

Comment: I recommend looking into using [`Polly`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). It's much easier than manually setting up retry cases yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (true)` is an infinite loop.
Instead, I would rather use a (boolean) variable to check in `while()`.
That gives you the opportunity to set this variable to `false` and avoid the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generally use `while (true)` (that's a potential infinite loop), even if you have somewhere a `break` statement it can sometimes happen that this statement might not be reached.

I would recommend a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "Some URL"))
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");                                
            response = await myHttpHelper.SendHttpRequest(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);                             
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wont this send the message 3 times?

Comment: @Magnus Yes, it will, but I think that would be a different question about improving the code overall

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable called `success` and use that as the while loop condition:

```
boolean success = false;
while (!success) {
    try
    {
        using (HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "Some URL"))
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");                                
            response = await myHttpHelper.SendHttpRequest(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);                             
        }
        success = true; <--- set to true here
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't go with Polly I would recommend a combination of @Sweeper's and @Magnus' reply:

```
const int retryLimit = 3;
boolean success = false;
int retryCounter = 0;

while (!success
        && retryCounter++ < retryLimit) {
    try
    {
        // http request as is

        success = true; 
    }
    // Exception handling
}
```

This way you controll the number of retries *and* jump out of the loop when the request is successful.